# Where does Eclipse itself put the self signed plugin cert, if not the cacerts file?

Tags: eclipse, ssl, certificate, keytool

I have a plugin jar that i'm trying to install silently.  I actually got it to work, despite having to use openssl to extract the cert and using `keytool.exe` to install it in the `/jre/lib/security/cacerts` as a trusted certificate.  It worked!

However, my dumb question:  when i install using the gui, and use the gui windows to click past the "Do you trust this certificate?" (yes, i do), where does the cert go?  After the (manual) install, if i use keytool to list the certs (`keytool -list -v -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`), I don't see any mention of the plugin i just installed.  I've looked at all the `cacerts` files i can find, none have any mention of my plugin.

Where does Eclipse itself put the cert, if not the cacerts file?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has its own secure storage.

Look in the Preferences in 'General > Security > Secure Storage'. The 'Contents' tab has the storage location.

Comment: Thank you for responding!
However, this seems to be for passwords, not certificates?
I also don't see any mention of my plugin anywhere.

This may not be exactly what I'm looking for.